# Drupal 8 live preview question

Tags: 8

I'm a designer who is doing a design review on a Drupal 8 website. I'm having trouble doing the design review because 'admin objects' are getting in the way of the full page design:

- Admin bar at top of screen
  [image]
- View, Edit, Up-Publish etc buttons below the header
  [image]
- Sticky provide feedback bar
  [image]

(Sorry can't show the full page due to NDA)

Usually I would just log out and preview live site, but the staging server for this project is hidden behind multiple logins and trying to access the website when not being logged in just redirects to the currently live (old) Drupal 7 website.

Any idea for how to remove these items and just preview the normal page?

Thanks

Comment: Run it locally?

Comment: Unfortunately running it locally isn't an option unfortunately, as we're working with a 3rd party development company who is only sharing staging site access.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a user without any special admin privileges.  Then you can either view it from another browser as the normal user or use the [Masquerade module](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) to swap in and out of that user from the same session.

Comment: That's the easiest approach. Keep in mind that if this is a site that users/editors are actively working with, they should be able to get a meaningful view of their result as well. The local tasks for example are a block. You can put them wherever you want and you can also override that template to render them for example outside of the active content (e.g. top-right corner). There is also an issue in admin_toolbar to support moving them into the toolbar.

Comment: Hi CG Monroe & Berdir, thanks for your responses, we'll try giving this approach a shot. Cheers